# Create a Power BI measure to report most recent nonblank value based on date and category

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm super new to Power BI & DAX, and I would like some help creating a measure that will report the most recent nonblank value based on date + two other category columns. I need to populate the grid "Desired output" using the table to the left, and showing the most recent nonblank 'Stage' for each 'Location' and 'Breed'. The colored values should be pulled from a previous date since the most recent date is blank.

[image: Image of a mock data table and desired output]

As of now my code works only partially - it shows not only the values for the most recent date, but also pre-populates the blanks with other values. However, it is not adding the right kind of data in the blank values. I suspect it is pulling just the most recent nonblank value from a previous date and disregarding 'Location' and 'Breed'. Here's the code I'm using:

```
Most Recent Stage Nonblank = 
  var thisdate = MAX(table[Date])
  var lastvaluenonblank = CALCULATE(
                              MAX(table[Date]),
                              NOT(table[Stage] = BLANK()),
                              table[Date] <= thisdate)

  RETURN IF(
           SELECTEDVALUE(table[Stage]) = BLANK(),
           CALCULATE(
              MAX(table[Stage]),
              table[Date] <= thisdate),
           SELECTEDVALUE(table[Stage]))
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using measure

```
Measure = 
var dt = CALCULATE(MAX(Data[Date]), ALLEXCEPT(Data, Data[Location], Data[Breed]), Data[Stage] <> BLANK())
return CALCULATE(MAX(Data[Stage]), Data[Date] = dt)
```

[image]